# Angular google map searchbox inside angular bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angular-google-maps

Im using these two cool Angular modules, [Angular Google Map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) and [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

What I want to achieve is to put the `google map` with a `search box` inside that `modal`, the map alone works fine but when I add a `search box` there are conflicts.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalTemplate.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div style="width:100%;">
                <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
                    <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchbox.template" events="searchbox.events"></ui-gmap-search-box>
                </ui-gmap-google-map>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

And on the map `controller` :

Here's the code for the `search box` `$scope.searchbox = { template:'<input type="text" placeholder="Search Box">', events:events};`

The map works fine except for the search box its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never, but I think the search box template string should be a path and not HTML. I tried the same with defining html in the template string, but that does not seem to work.

*If you check the browser console when you use html instead of a path string you'l see that there is a "404 not found" for the template.*

---

**In my project I use the following setup:**

My HTML for the map and the searchbox:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options" control="map.control">
       <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchBox.template" events="searchBox.events" options="searchBox.options"></ui-gmap-search-box>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And the following code for the searchbox in my controller:

```
$scope.searchBox = {
    template: 'app/components/setting/area/newarea/searchTemplate.html',
    options: {
        autocomplete: true,
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: bounderies }
    },
    events: {
        place_changed: function (searchBox) { }
    }
}
```

***The options are used for Google maps hints when typing in the search box***

In the searchTemplate.html I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{'FINDLOCATION' | translate}}">
```

***The {{'FINDLOCATION' | translate}} is used for pascalprecht translate.***

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the places libraries when you included the google maps api? If not this might be the reason. Also check if the events var is initialized.

Like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false

var events = {
        places_changed: function (searchBox) {
            //do something
        }
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure it's included. I included it on the google API URL. `<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.pac-container {
  z-index: 1051;
}
```